# Ubuntu server loses exactly 5 minutes once in a while

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, date-time, clock

I noticed that my server, an Ubuntu server 12.04, was losing time. I figured the hardware clock was off or maybe dying due to a faulty CMOS battery. I installed NTP to ensure the drift would be corrected, but to no avail. During a day it would lose 20 minutes or so.

To debug, I created a small cron job to check against a remote servers time, which I knew to be correct. The script calculates the difference in seconds between local and remote time. The NTP service was **not running** during these tests.

The result was interesting. It seems to be losing exactly 5 minutes several times during the day. Look at this log (difference from remote server noted in seconds):

```
Tue Oct 23 03:30:02 CEST 2012: 284
Tue Oct 23 03:35:02 CEST 2012: 284
Tue Oct 23 03:40:01 CEST 2012: 285
Tue Oct 23 03:45:02 CEST 2012: 285
Tue Oct 23 03:50:02 CEST 2012: 285
Tue Oct 23 03:55:02 CEST 2012: 284
Tue Oct 23 04:00:02 CEST 2012: 284
Tue Oct 23 04:05:01 CEST 2012: 285
Tue Oct 23 04:10:01 CEST 2012: 285
Tue Oct 23 04:15:02 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 04:20:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 04:25:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 04:30:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 04:35:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 04:40:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 04:45:02 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 04:50:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 04:55:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 05:00:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 05:05:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 05:10:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 05:15:02 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 05:20:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 05:25:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 05:30:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 05:35:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 05:40:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 05:45:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 05:50:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 05:55:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 06:00:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 06:05:03 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 06:10:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 06:15:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 06:20:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 06:25:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 06:30:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 06:35:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 06:40:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 06:45:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 06:50:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 06:55:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 07:00:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 07:05:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 07:10:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 07:15:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 07:20:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 07:25:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 07:30:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 07:35:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 07:40:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 07:45:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 07:50:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 07:55:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 08:00:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 08:05:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 08:10:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 08:15:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 08:20:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 08:25:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 08:30:01 CEST 2012: 585
Tue Oct 23 08:35:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 08:40:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 08:45:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 08:50:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 08:55:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:00:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:05:03 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:10:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:15:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:20:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:25:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:30:01 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:35:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:40:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:45:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:50:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 09:55:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 10:00:01 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 10:05:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 10:10:07 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 10:15:02 CEST 2012: 584
Tue Oct 23 10:20:02 CEST 2012: 884
Tue Oct 23 10:25:02 CEST 2012: 884
Tue Oct 23 10:30:02 CEST 2012: 883
Tue Oct 23 10:35:01 CEST 2012: 884
Tue Oct 23 10:40:02 CEST 2012: 884
Tue Oct 23 10:45:02 CEST 2012: 884
Tue Oct 23 10:50:02 CEST 2012: 884
Tue Oct 23 10:55:02 CEST 2012: 1184
Tue Oct 23 11:00:02 CEST 2012: 1183
Tue Oct 23 11:05:01 CEST 2012: 1184
Tue Oct 23 11:10:02 CEST 2012: 1184
Tue Oct 23 11:15:02 CEST 2012: 1184
Tue Oct 23 11:20:02 CEST 2012: 1184
```

This does not seem to be faulty CMOS battery in my opinion. But what do you think?

EDIT:

When I enable NTP, this is the output of ntpq -p:

```
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
dns02.wsrs.net  .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
brick.steinhoff 71.40.128.157    3 u    1   64    1  144.031  1499785   0.002
chime6.surfnet. .PPS.            1 u    -   64    1   22.663  1499789   0.002
ntp0.mediamatic .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
europium.canoni .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
```

EDIT 2:

After ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com

```
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
kvm01.roethof.n 213.154.236.182  3 u   10   64    1   34.918   -1.980   0.002
ntp0.bbactive.e 193.79.237.14    2 u    9   64    1   58.378    6.956   0.002
16-164-ftth.ons 193.79.237.14    2 u    8   64    1   30.202    5.697   0.002
kameli.miuku.ne 62.237.86.238    2 u    7   64    1  106.975   -9.806   0.002
europium.canoni 193.79.237.14    2 u    6   64    1   42.010    6.381   0.002
```

Comment: But what does `ntpq -p` say and what NTP records are in syslog? AFAIK the CMOS clock is normally only consulted at boot.

Comment: Well, I disabled NTP for the purpose of the test. I just tried enabling it and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Well a) You have to correct the huge error in time (1499785 ms) before ntp can attempt to sync - try `ntpdate` first. b) you need to wait more than a few seconds.

Comment: Well, as I've said, NTP has been running, and yet, sometimes it loses 300 seconds anyway. As this happens regularly, that will ruin NTP sync as well - right?

Comment: NTP operates not by making huge jumps but by slewing time (it can take 2000s to correct a 1s offset). Just because NTP is running doesn't mean NTP can instantly correct a huge time offset. Use `ntpdate`. NTP will usefully report timekeeping anomalies in syslog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I figured the hardware clock was off or maybe dying due to a faulty CMOS battery.**

The CMOS clock is only read when you boot the operating system.

> **I installed NTP to ensure the drift would be corrected, but to no avail.**

NTP isn't intended to correct a huge offset. You can make that correction using `ntpdate`, then start ntpd and after a few hours check `ntpq -p` and make sure you understand what it is telling you. Then look in syslog for NTP complaints.

> **NTP has been running, and yet, sometimes it loses 300 seconds anyway**

If so, I'd expect to see NTP comment on this in syslog - this will tell you exactly when the problem occurs. Perhaps this coincides with a cron job or some external event. I'd follow up such clues. I'm assuming you'd notice if a hardware fault was freezing the system for 5 minutes at a time.

---

**Troubleshooting NTP**

I'd read [Troubleshooting NTP](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/TroubleshootingNTP) especially the "Known Issues" sections.

---

**Monitoring Time**

Harold already has a script, for others here's a couple of ideas:

On badserver enable RFC868 time protocol

```
vi /etc/xinetd.d/time-stream
# change `disable=yes` to `disable=no`
kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/xinetd.pid)
```

On goodserver use cron to schedule once a minute

```
date -u; TZ=utc rdate badserver > /tmp/badserver-time.log
```

Or better, write a script that only logs failures to respond or large changes in offset between goodserver and badserver.

Comment: I always ensure to run ntpdate before starting the NTP service, so I am sure the time is correct from the start. Whatever is going on here, it is not related to the NTP service, as it happens with or without the service running. I will keep an eye on the syslog, though.

Comment: NTP daemon is up, date is correct. I will look at syslog next time it falls behind. I am only working on the machine through SSH, and unfortunately only over wifi. Since the connection has been dropping from time to time, it could actually be happening simultaneously (in a system freeze). I will try to confirm this.

Comment: At 18:27 (UTC+2), my wifi SSH connection went out for exactly 300 seconds along with all other web services, and at 18:32 I was able to log in again. The system clock had not updated during the fallout. This is a much bigger problem, it seems... what could cause a 300 second fallout every 3 to 4 hours?

Comment: Oh yeah, and nothing was logged during the system breakdown either...

Comment: Wild wild guess: some unusual and flaky peripheral and a bad driver. I'd consider gradually stripping away non-essential peripherals and services until a culprit is found. Good luck.

Comment: Actually, there is an external USB soundcard connected to it. I'll start there. Thank you for your help so far. Will return when I know more.

Comment: Still no luck, though it seems that it sometimes loses SMB connection to a NAS I have, and that timeout is exactly 300 seconds. So now I'm considering if this could cause a system clock freeze. Seems like the likely candidate, and it is in fstab, but it's still strange behaviour.